# Do not allow '.'(dot) anywhere in a string (regular expression)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression for allowing unicode chars in names(Spanish, Japanese etc), but I don't want to allow '.'(dot) anywhere in the string.

I have tried this regex but it fails when string length is less than 3. I am using xRegExp.

`^[^.][\\pL ,.'-‘’][^.]+$`

For Example:

```
NOËL             // true
Sanket ketkar    // true
.sank            // false
san. ket         // false
NOËL.some        // false
```

Basically it should return false when name has '.' in it.

Comment: To clarify, do you wish to match every line between `dot`s, or do you want every line that does not contain a dot?

Comment: It would help if would include some sample inputs and desired output along with the original question

Comment: Here you go:
```john mikel       -> true
wu                   -> true
.wu                  -> false
j.ohn mikel      -> false
```
Basically it should return true for any string except for the one containing dots
To be more clear I am using this for name validation in an input. Would this help?

Comment: That does help quite a bit. Also, you wish to match only spanish names, is that correct?

Comment: its not just spanish, but it should allow spanish characters

Comment: Is there a specific list of languages it should allow, or just english and spanish?

Comment: I think `^[\\pL ,.'-‘’]+$` was working fine for any unicode chars I want to keep returning true for any unicode word not specific to a partiular language

Comment: I believe you meant `\p{L}` instead of `\\pL`, to match any unicode letter. I'll update my answer to include that

Comment: yep, that will do

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern `^[^.][\\pL ,.'-‘’][^.]+$` matches at least 3 characters because you use 3 characters classes, where the first 2 expect to match at least 1 character and the last one matches 1 or more times.

You could remove the dot from your character class and repeat that character class only to match 1+ times any of the listed to also match when there are less than 3 characters.

```
^[\p{L} ,'‘’-]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aezRzX/1)

---

Or you could use a  [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated):

```
^[^.\r\n]+$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[^.\r\n]+` Negated character class, match any char except a dot or newline
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OYAOd9/1)

Comment: Why you added `\r\n`, that are not in the question?

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
^[\p{L},\-\s‘’]+(?!\.)$
```

As seen here: **https://regex101.com/r/ireqbW/5**

## Explanation -

The first part of the regex `[\p{L},\-\s‘’]+` matches any unicode letter, hyphen or space (given by `\s`)

`(?!\.)` is a Negative LookAhead in regex, which basically tells the regex that for each match, it should not be followed by a `.`

Comment: I think something is missing. This does not pass names containing numbers or special char like '(' or ')'.
My requirement is that any string is okay except for the one containing a dot

Comment: Your negative lookahead `(?!\.)$` cannot ever match anything and is therefore completely superfluous. You'll never find a single dot following an end-of-line. This regex is functionally identical to (though perhaps slower than) `^[\p{L},\-\s‘’]+$`

Answer (score 1):

`^[^.]+$`

It will match any non-empty string that does not contain a dot between the start and the end of the string.

If there is a dot somewhere between start to end (i.e. anywhere) it will fail.